# Wipe sheet clean

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently building out a sheet and trying to add a button that has a script assigned to clear a range. I just cannot get it to work and I've tried a few things I found on SO but no luck.
ranges I am trying to clear at the click of a button are A3:C32, G3:Q32.
A3:C32 are text fields and G3:Q32 are checkbox fields that have conditional formatting.
essentially user clicks the button and clears everything in mentioned ranges so they can refill the page without loosing conditioning through G3:Q32.
Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and be more specific about what you found (i.e. include links and the most relevant parts of each of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Clear Datavalidations and content

```
function clearall() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["A3:C32", "G3:Q32", "A3:C32", "G3:Q32"]).getRanges();
  rgl.forEach(r => {
    r.clearDataValidations().clearContent()
  })
}
```

Comment: function clearall() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["A3:C32", "G3:Q32", "A3:C32", "G3:Q32"]).getRanges();
  rgl.forEach(r => {
    r.clearDataValidations().clearContent()
  })
}

This worked I just had to remove the .clearDataValidations() as it removed the checkboxes I had. But it worked as intended. Thing you!!

Comment: I thought you wanted to remove the checkboxes